# How to write firestore rules with session cookies for authentication

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, next.js, firebase-security

I have used this https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-cookies to implement session cookies into my next.js application.

Having no client user authentication, I assume I have to handle all my firestore calls and permissions inside my server-side api; which begs the question.
What use do I have of the firestore rules? Is that just obsolete?

I'm asking because I don't see a way to authenticate anything with the rules - seeing as the `request.auth` will always be null? I'm pretty sure I'm getting something wrong here since on that doc for session cookies I see no mention that that will basically invalidate the .rules, yet I'm struggling to implement them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detect authenticated users in Firestore security rules while using Firebase session cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61383814/detect-authenticated-users-in-firestore-security-rules-while-using-firebase-sess)

Comment: @RJC I did read that, though I may have not fully understood it. I have to use the admin SDK instead of the normal one and validate on my API. No problem. My question is now are the .rules obsolete? Do I just remove them?

Comment: Another note as well, why would I even need to have to firebase-admin if the rules are useless? I don't need to bypass the rules as the rules will never work, so why implement the rules at all?

Comment: You can try to check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62032665/16531380) that tackles Firebase Authentication SDKs automatically persist the user state between page/app reloads, and try to restore that state upon the restart.

Answer (score 0):

Serverside rendering in NextJs has most of its benefits tied to reading data. If your security for reading items in a collection is not important I would leave the rules open.

If you do need to lock down reads (and or writes) but still want to fetch the data from a serverside function I would suggest using Cloud Functions.

Cloud functions uses the Admin SDK which will always override your rules and allow your database operations to succeed in the edge case that you are using SSR.

Comment: I don't understand well. So if I use SSR , we should call Firestore with Nextjs Api not from traditional client firestore ?

Answer (score 0):

Firebase rules are created to be used when a request is made a client side, like a website or a mobile application.
Literally, a public website is making direct requests to the Firestore database, without touching any of your backend server, like Node.js or Next.JS API.

### Firebase session for Next.JS

In the case of session management, you are taking responsibility of authorization and all requests on your backend.

Firebasre session contains claims as mentioned in the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-cookies). So, it is possible to add a middleware in Next.JS and check for claims:

```
req.claims = await getAuth().verifySessionCookie(sessionCookie, true);
```

and then somewhere in API check

```
if (req.claims?.admin) throw new Error('Denied');
```

### Security rules

As all requests to Firebase are done from your Next.JS backend API, it makes sense to disable all reads and writes to the Firestore DB from client applications:

```
rules_version = '2';

service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if false;
    }
  }
}
```

This is very important. If not set properly, the data might be publicly available to anyone in the Internet.

Your backend API will use `firebase-admin` package, which allows admin access to all Firebase resources and will overcome the client side rules above.

### Downsides of Firebase session

> For security reasons, Firebase session cookies cannot be used with other Firebase services due to their custom validity period, which can be set to the maximum duration of 2 weeks.

Currently Firebase does not allow to make requests to Services from clients side using session keys. So, subscription to DB changes feature on client side is not available. The only way to request Services is via your backend API and `firebase-admin`.